# Нужны ли в данном предложении тире?

Tags: пунктуация

Он вспомнил, сказал, что есть места в двух ближних школах, но одна из них — с физическим уклоном, а вторая — с немецким языком.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Можно оставить два тире:

**Он вспомнил, сказал, что есть места в двух ближних школах, но одна из них — с физическим уклоном, а вторая — с немецким языком.**

Первое тире ставится в предложении эллиптического типа, а перед вторым тире дополнительно пропущено слово "школа".

Comment: Согласен, но почему во втором случае обязательно нужна школа? это не частный случай парцелляции?

Answer (score 0):

Первое тире не ставится, а второе - да, в качестве замещения слов "одна из них", либо " одна из школ".

Comment: Вы что же, предлагаете пропустить сказуемое в неполном предложении и не поставить тире? И тире (эллипсис) не ставится взамен подлежащего, в эллиптических предложениях пропускается глагол-сказуемое.